# Tensorflow Estimators : proper way to train image grids separately

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to train an object detection model as described in this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8281079)

There are 3 fully connected layers with 512, 512, 25 neurons. The 16x55x55 feature map from the last convolutional layer is fed into the fully connected layers to retrieve the appropriate class. At this stage, every grid described by (16x1x1) is fed into the fully connected layers to classify the grid as belonging to one of the 25 classes. The structure can be seen in the pciture below

[fully connected layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpbwm.png)

I am trying to adapt the code from TF MNIST classification tutorial, and I would like to know if it is okay to just sum the losses from each grid as in the code snippet below and use it to train the model weights.

```html
flat_fmap = tf.reshape(last_conv_layer, [-1, 16*55*55])

total_loss = 0

for grid of flat_fmap:
  dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=grid, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  dense2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense1, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense2, units=25)

  total_loss += tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
  

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(
  loss=total_loss,
  global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())


return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, loss=total_loss, train_op=train_op)
```

In the code above, I think at every iteration 3 new layers are being creating. However, I would like the weights to be preserved when classifying one grid and then another.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the total_loss should be ok.

tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is also adding losses together.

It calculates a sparse_softmax with logits and then reduces the resulting array though a sum using math_ops.reduce_sum. 
So you are adding them together, one way or another.

[As you can see in its source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py)

The for loop on the network declaration seems unusual, it probably makes more sense to do it at run time and pass each grid through the feed_dict.

```
dense1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=X, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dense2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense1, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense2, units=25)
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)
total_loss = 0


with tf.session as sess:
   sess.run(init) 
   for grid in flat_fmap:
       _, l = sess.run([optimizer,loss], feed_dict{X: grid, labels=labels})

       total_loss += l
```

Comment: I see, thank you. What about the declaration of dense1 dense2 layers inside the for loop? It seems like for every grid I am generating a brand new layer and then having the grid pass through it. I would like to make sure every grid passes through the same dense layers and the training is done based on the total loss.

Comment: you are right. that does look odd. added a few more details in pseudocode, let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. I think the pseudocode you provided would work if I only was working with the image grids. However, in my model, the image 500x500 goes through several convolutional and pooling layers before being processed as grids. What I am looking for is a way to integrate all of the layers into one model_function that I can pass to Estimator to train. As for the code, I am referring to the TF CNN tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn.